# Piano rhythm patterns

Tags: piano, chords

What written resources can be recommended to an advanced classically trained piano player looking to learn rhythm patterns for piano chords to accompany jazz/latin/popular music?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Maybe you could give a few more details as to what you're having trouble with? I have no training on keyboard at all but generally find I can listen to a song a couple of times and pick out the chords and melody and figure out how it works rhythmically. Have you tried just doing things by ear? It seems that with your training you'd have a great head start....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [60 Top Hat Piano Grooves](http://mdecks.com/pianovol1.phtml). It has 60 different grooves in all different styles including Jazz, Latin, pop and rock. You must be a pretty advanced player to play some of the grooves, it is all in music notation and explained using videos, very useful if you know how to read well.